# Program does not accept any user input

Tags: python, validation, user-input

I'm trying to get this program to accept a number between 1 and 1000. What am I missing?

```
def main ( ):
    getGuestCnt ( )

def getGuestCnt ( ):
    guests = input("Please enter the number of guests: ")
    while guests != isValidGuest ( guests ):
        print ("Invalid! Enter only positive whole numbers.")
        guests = input ("Please enter the number of guests: ")
    return int(guests)

def isValidGuest ( guests ):
    return ((str(guests).isdigit()) and (int(guests) >= 0 and int(guests) <= 1000 ))

main ( )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isValidGuest` returns a boolean expression - you shouldn't compare it to the inputed number, just check if it's `True` or `False`:

```
while not isValidGuest ( guests ):
    print ("Invalid! Enter only positive whole numbers.")
    guests = input ("Please enter the number of guests: ")
```

Answer (score 0):

In your while condition, you compare guests variable with you test.
What you really what to do is this:

```
...
while not isValidGuest(guests):
    ...
```